# Distance functions used in clustering analysis

Tags: geometric-deep-learning, clustering, non-euclidean-data

From what I've seen in clustering, distance is taken as a hyper parameter (which is to be selected) when inferring the relationships/clusters between points.  Examples of distances I've come across are Euclidean, taxicab, Mahalanorbis, and Minoowski.

What are some examples of highly-cited papers doing this, and is there any concrete empirical evidence supporting this practice?  And what non-Euclidean distance functions do they use?

Comment: _supporting this practice_ what practice? hyper-parameters tuning?

Comment: No Turing the distance function as s hyperparameter